# Value is not coming inside the thumb of the UISlider

Tags: iphone, uislider

This is the code I am using to display the value of the slider inside my thumb image. But still the value is getting displayed below the slider. Please help me.

```
-(IBAction)sliderValueChanged:(id)sender 
{
    UISlider *aSlider = (UISlider *)sender;
    [aSlider setThumbImage:
        [self addText:self.thumbImage text:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f",
        aSlider.value * 100]] forState:aSlider.state];
}

//Add text to UIImage 

-(UIImage *)addText:(UIImage *)img text:(NSString *)text1{ 
    int w = img.size.width; 
    int h = img.size.height; 
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(); 
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, w, h, 8, 4 * w, 
        colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst); 
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, w, h), img.CGImage); 

    char* text= (char *)[text1 cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]; 
    CGContextSelectFont(context, "Arial",12, kCGEncodingMacRoman); 
    CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(context, kCGTextFill); 
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0, 0, 0, 1); 
    CGContextShowTextAtPoint(context,3,8,text, strlen(text)); 
    CGImageRef imgCombined = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context); 

    CGContextRelease(context); 
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace); 

    UIImage *retImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imgCombined]; 
    CGImageRelease(imgCombined); 

    return retImage;
```

Comment: Actually you just need to change the values in CGCOntextShowTextAtPoint to see it in your thumb. I just finished working on this and this is working perfectly fine. The only thing i am looking for is if there is a way to change the color of the font.

Comment: And to change the color of the text you can change the method CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context,255,255,255, 1);according to your need.